# Getting error while running "open" command

Tags: ubuntu, unix

I am getting the below error while running open command in Windows Ubuntu. Please advise.

```
root@DESKTOP-L9PGIBR:/tmp# open sample.txt
open: ioctl(VT_GETSTATE): Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

Comment: Why do you want to open the file? Maybe just try `cat sample.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `open` command has nothing to do with simply opening a textfile: it's about starting a program on a virtual terminal.

What you most probably try to do, is open the file for reading purposes. For that, you might use a text editor, like `vi`, `emacs` or `xemacs` (you might check how those text editors work before actually starting to use them, it's quite complicated).

Other ways are `cat` or `more`, standard UNIX commands you can use for:

- in case of `cat`: dumping the content of the whole textfile on your terminal
- in case of `more`: use a more interactive way of showing the content.